# Display specific Taxonomy Term from Custom Post Type

Tags: customization, taxonomy

I have looked at multiple posts, but no luck. I need to use the loop how I have it for existing purposes, but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to return the terms of a custom taxonomy within a custom post type. Here is my code:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( 

    'post_type' => 'dealmaker_pt', 
    'taxonomy' => 'topics',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'dealoftheweek',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'offset' => 1 ) 
); 
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
?>

stuffs here

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

My post type is `dealmaker_pt` and my taxonomy is `topics` and I'm trying to display the specific taxonomy term of `dealoftheweek`.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You want only display the "dealmaker_pt" object where "topics = dealoftheweek" ? That doesn't work if you go to URL http:/ /DOMAIN/topics/dealoftheweek ?

Comment: No, I am currently getting a server 500 error unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use valid format for this [Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Example:

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'topics',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'dealoftheweek',
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'dealmaker_pt',
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'offset' => 1 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you, I marked the answer as the correct solution. Just doesn't show.